# Can't change variable in Chrome Developer Tools Console

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, developer-tools

I used to be able to put a break point in a javascript function and change variable values to debug.  This worked until recently (within a week or two).

Here's an example:

```
function test(params) {
  var result = params.num * 2;

  // if I put a break point here and change result = undefined,
  // it doesn't work
  return result;  
}


// I should get 6, but when debugging and changing result to undefined,
// I should get undefined in my output, used to, not anymore    
var x = test({ num: 3 });

console.log(x);
```

I'm using OSX Yosemite Chrome v. 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit)

It is up to date and I just restarted Chrome.

I do this all the time, but something happened recently and I can't anymore.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this was documented behavior for a while.  Just yesterday a change was made to the code that says it will restore the ability to change variables.  It is very disappointing that they allowed it to break for any length of time.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=569811&q=debugger%20change%20variable&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Based on this answer, I downloaded Chrome Canary v51.0.2696.0, it works.  Can't wait for them to include the fix in the office release.  I'll use the Canary version if I need this feature until then.  Thanks Brian!!!

Comment: can't change the value of a variable still.  stuck in an infinite loop, trying to break out of it by changing a variable being tested against.  I can change it in the inspector or console, but then when i print the value again or refresh the watch it's back to the old value!